# yo: command not found after installation on Mac machine

Tags: node.js

After installation of yo using this command:

```
npm install -g yo
```

i got the following output:

```
/Users/admin/npm/bin/yo -> 
/Users/admin/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
/Users/admin/npm/bin/yo-complete -> 
/Users/admin/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js

> yo@2.0.0 postinstall /Users/admin/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor
```

Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Everything looks all right!
/Users/admin/npm/lib
└── yo@2.0.0

But when i run

```
yo --version
```

i got: command not found: yo

Comment: Did you initially install Node using Homebrew?

Comment: @robertklep yes

Comment: It's not going to solve your immediate issue (see the posted answer for that), but Homebrew-installed Node is really a PITA because it uses non-standard paths to install executables, which then end up not being in your `$PATH`. If you feel like it, you should uninstall Node with Homebrew and use the official Node.js installer for Mac: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `/Users/admin/npm/bin/` to your PATH-variable. To do that just add `export PATH="/Users/admin/npm/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bash_profile` which resides in your home directory, so you don't have to manually change your path every time you start the terminal application.

In order to make that work you need to restart the terminal or manually execute your bash_profile. To check if everything worked out just output your path (using the command `echo $PATH`) and check if the added directory is part of it. Then also the command `which yo` should point you to the correct executable.